Alignment of references in latex
I have to create one .tex file for final submission to IEEE Trans., I generated bibitems from the bib file and placed it inside the main .tex file. However, the first word of each reference is slightly shifted towards the right (alignment issues with other lines). Any help would be appreciated a lot, I attached a minimal example for better understanding.
\documentclass[journal, ]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\title{Example}
 
\author{ABC
 
\thanks{  }
\thanks{  }}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
   This is just an example

\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
NTT, ABC
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{W}{ith} Quantum Computer, current PKC algorithms are at risk \cite{rsa} and elliptic curve cryptography \cite{ecc},\cite{shor} \cite{kyber}. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEE}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{rsa}
R.~L. Rivest, A.~Shamir, and L.~Adleman, ``A method for obtaining digital
  signatures and public-key cryptosystems,'' \emph{Communications of the ACM},
  vol.~21, no.~2, pp. 120--126, 1978.

\bibitem{ecc}
V.~S. Miller, ``Use of elliptic curves in cryptography,'' in \emph{Conference
  on the theory and application of cryptographic techniques}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Springer, 1985, pp. 417--426.

\bibitem{shor}
P.~W. Shor, ``Algorithms for quantum computation: discrete logarithms and
  factoring,'' in \emph{Proceedings 35th annual symposium on foundations of
  computer science}.\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax IEEE, 1994, pp.
  124--134.
  
\bibitem{kyber}
R.~Avanzi, J.~Bos, L.~Ducas, E.~Kiltz, T.~Lepoint, V.~Lyubashevsky, J.~M.
  Schanck, P.~Schwabe, G.~Seiler, and D.~Stehl{\'e}, ``{CRYSTALS}-{K}yber
  algorithm specifications and supporting documentation,'' \emph{NIST PQC
  Round}, vol.~2, no.~4, pp. 1--43, 2019.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


Different online converters

The thebibliography environment has one mandatory argument which specifies the widest number of the labels. If you have less than 10 items, choose e.g. 9 (it does not matter much as long as you don't take 1). If you have less than 100 items, choose e.g. 99 etc.
\documentclass[journal, ]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\title{Example}
 
\author{ABC
 
\thanks{  }
\thanks{  }}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
   This is just an example

\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
NTT, ABC
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{W}{ith} Quantum Computer, current PKC algorithms are at risk \cite{rsa} and elliptic curve cryptography \cite{ecc},\cite{shor} \cite{kyber}. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEE}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{rsa}
R.~L. Rivest, A.~Shamir, and L.~Adleman, ``A method for obtaining digital
  signatures and public-key cryptosystems,'' \emph{Communications of the ACM},
  vol.~21, no.~2, pp. 120--126, 1978.

\bibitem{ecc}
V.~S. Miller, ``Use of elliptic curves in cryptography,'' in \emph{Conference
  on the theory and application of cryptographic techniques}.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Springer, 1985, pp. 417--426.

\bibitem{shor}
P.~W. Shor, ``Algorithms for quantum computation: discrete logarithms and
  factoring,'' in \emph{Proceedings 35th annual symposium on foundations of
  computer science}.\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax IEEE, 1994, pp.
  124--134.
  
\bibitem{kyber}
R.~Avanzi, J.~Bos, L.~Ducas, E.~Kiltz, T.~Lepoint, V.~Lyubashevsky, J.~M.
  Schanck, P.~Schwabe, G.~Seiler, and D.~Stehl{\'e}, ``{CRYSTALS}-{K}yber
  algorithm specifications and supporting documentation,'' \emph{NIST PQC
  Round}, vol.~2, no.~4, pp. 1--43, 2019.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}



Thank you for the reply, it solves this problem. However, some ref. numbers are changed. The journal may see this as a major change after acceptance. How to keep the same numbers as done automatically by the bibtex.

@Khalid This should not change any ref numbers. This just influences the spacing.

@Khalid Please create a small test file which demonstrates how the numbers change.

The numbers (in text ) do not appear in ascending order, like in the introduction section, the references are [1], [2], [3], and then [14].

@Khalid The numbers are in the same order as you have the \bibitems in the thebibliography environment. If you want a different order, order the bibitem as you want them.
